# Location Anonimity and Skyhook

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn

I am a fairly paranoid computer user, and to protect myself online I always use a VPN.

However, I note that while my IP is anonymized, my location is not. Some websites will present me with my real location instead of the location of the VPN gateway. I gather this is done by Skyhook like software that scans the available wireless networks.

Needless to say, I find this a bit disturbing and invasive.

Is it possible to stop this somehow? As an additional challenge I travel frequently, so wifi is usually my only connection option.

Comment: can you give us an example of a site which was able to locate you despite your using a VPN?

Comment: When I log into my VPN gateway in say, Sweden, and go to a site such as http://whatismyipaddress.com/ It will report my location as Sweden.

However when I go to any Google site (such as youtube) it will redirect me to a German version which is my actual location.

Comment: Then you are not using a VPN. When I use a VPN, whatismyipaddress.com cannot identify me. Can you tell me which kind of VPN you are using? pptp, openvpn, IPSec...

Comment: PPTP
Sorry My comment was submitted before completion. IP detection websites detect my gateway, not my physical location. Google sites detect my physical location.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried erasing all of your cookies? Yet I must warn you: there is no defense. This year I am away from the US, I have an OpenVPN at work (in New Jersey), through which I try to access my bank account, Netflix, and so on. Some sites identify me as being from outside the US, and deny me service. So if that is your problem, there is nothing I can do, sorry.

Comment: I'm not interested in circumventing this-- what do you mean 'there is no defense'. I'm just interested in how they do it and bloacking that if at all possible. Is it "Skyhook"-esque geolocating via available wifi networks? Or is my browser leaking some information I don't know about: if it's leaking my location it could be leaking other information as well.

Comment: Like I said, there is not much I know. What I know is that some sites can get around my OpenVPN (no skyhook technique here, I am doing everything via ethernet), but they fail (i.e., they do not detect my true connection) when I use TOR through Whonix. Since Whonix is optimized to prevent leakages, I suspect the technique employed is some sort of undisclosed leakage. Once again, Whonix assures your geolocation is not detected. Only problem is, it is cumbersome and slow.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting-- I was almost certain skyhook was to blame. I guess I should read up on the full suite of techniques employed by whonix. Thanks for your input. This makes me think it may have something to do with the difference between a proxy and a VPN-- since TOR is proxy based.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers that support geolocation APIs usually give you privacy options to control them. What browser (& version) are you using, on which OS (& version)? What plugins and browser extensions are you running? Have you looked at your privacy options in your browser?

If you turn off all browser plug-ins and extensions, as well as disabling Java and JavaScript, do you still have the problem? If so, then try also doing a full browser reset where you ditch all cookies or other website data. Do you still have the problem? If not, try doing a process-of-elimination to see what's allowing the information leak.

My guess is that some sites look at what IP address their web server sees you as coming from, and does GeoIP on that, and thus they think you're located where your VPN server is. Whereas other sites run a JavaScript (which executes in the browser on your client) that looks at your IP address and does GeoIP on *that*, and thus they know where you really are.